# French regex zipcode

Tags: php, regex, pcre, zipcode

I need a regex for check french zip code in PHP.

I have a regex like :

`/^(([\d]{2} )|(2[abAB] ))*(([\d]{2})|(2[abAB]))$/` capturing 01 to 99 or 2a or 2b
or
`^[0-9]{5}$` capturing 01000 to 99000
or
`^(0[1-9]|[1-8]\d|9[0-5])\d{3}$` capturing 01000 to 95999

In reality i need a combo of this 3 regex,
Can capture 01 to 95, or 01000 to 95000 or 971 to 978 or 984 to 989 or 2A or 2a or 2B or 2b

Any idea ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: So close, but 95000 is accepted, but not 95999, and 2a / 2A and 2b / 2B not working.

Comment: Very perfect, thanks thanks thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
(?:0[1-9]|[13-8][0-9]|2[ab1-9]|9[0-5])(?:[0-9]{3})?|9[78][1-9](?:[0-9]{2})?
```

Have a look at: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_postal_en_France

Comment: @Buck: `86000` exists, it is Poitiers prefecture of Vienne.

Comment: @Buck: see my edit, I've made city number optional, so it matches department only or city zip code.

Comment: Sorry i read to fast, 86000 is ok :D
I use the chris85 solution, thanks for all :)

Comment: @Buck: OK, but chris95 solution matches `20xxx` that don't exist but doesn't match `95xxx` (Val d'Oise)

Comment: Exact :/ it's fixed for 95xxx but not for exept 20xxx. I try to fix that.

Comment: Thanks Toto for this regex :)

Comment: @Buck My regex was written for the rules you wrote (`01000 to 95999`). The 20k is allowed because of the `[1-8]\d` which is paired with `(?:\d{3})?)` for 20ks. It seems like there were more rules so you should accept this answer.

Comment: Yes, regex is a complex world, thank for you two :) i forget we haven't 2xxxx department, my bad chris85 ;)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your specifications I think:

```
^(?:(?:(?:0[1-9]|[1-8]\d|9[0-4])(?:\d{3})?)|97[1-8]|98[4-9]|‌​‌​2[abAB])$
```

will meet your requirements. Your regex had issues with the ranges and spaces.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/wFnEDj/2/